# Selenium split webelement text and use to click

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to take value from decimal field which will be dynamic eg. value of that field is "12.01". Then I need to take all the numbers and convert those to separate int's and use is as input for the numpad keyboard.

Steps:

1. Getting value from the field
2. Transferring those into string:

   var nums = new string(textFromElement.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());

From value: "12.01" I have variable nums as: "1201"

3. Use this numbers as separate int's inside a method

driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format(locator, Separatenumber))).Click();

I suppose I need to create foreach loop but first of all I need to separate ints, how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string into a char array and then convert it into an int array

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(nums, c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));
```